# SelectOneMenu changes its value only after the refresh

Tags: java, jsf

I use a `SelectOneMenu` component and a `SelectBooleanCheckbox` component on my JSF page.

If the combo box is selected, my SelectOneMenu should be blocked and is set to the first element (reset).

Now I have value change listener for combobox implemented and blocking of the `SelectOneMenu` works very well.

But, when I reset the ComboBox, the `SelectOneMenu` is set to the old (previous) element.

I think there is something like cache used by JSF.

How do I reset the `SelectOneMenu` control?

I have linked the `value`-attribute to the bean property. I set a value for this attribute in the value change listener.

Thanks!

Comment: @BalusC JSF 1.x and session scoped beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you're using `immediate="true"` on the checkbox and that you're calling [`FacesContext#renderResponse()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse%28%29) in your value change listener method (otherwise you would go mad with validations).

In that case, you need to set the value of the dropdown component itself to `null` as well.

```
UIInput dropdown = (UIInput) facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent("formid:dropdownid");
dropdown.setValue(null);
```

An alternative to [`UIViewroot#findComponent()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) is to bind it as bean property.

```
<h:selectOneMenu binding="#{bean.dropdown}">
```